# Inner joining on to temp table and insert to table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, inner-join, temp-tables

I have a list of strings. Each of them have categories which are separated out by a '/'.

For example:

animals/domestic/dog

animals/domestic/cat

What I want to do with these categories is to insert into a MySql categories table.
The table has 4 columns: 
id (int auto increment), category_name (nvarchar), parent_id (int), is_active (bit)

The logic around inserting these should be as follows:

The main categories (animals) should have a parent_id of 0.

The child categories will have the id of their parent as parent_id.

There cannot be two active categories with the same category name.

I have tried to implement the following logic:

1. Get a distinct list of strings.
2. From these, get a distinct list of main categories.
3. Insert the distinct main categories to the categories table with a parent ID of 0.
4. Organise each of the categories in pairs and get distinct pairs:

(animals, domestic)

(domestic, dog)

(domestic, cat)

5. Get the matching id for each of the parent categories and insert in to the child's parent_id

SQL:

```
/*INSERT ALL THE FIRST PARENT CATEGORIES WITH A PARENT ID OF 0*/
            INSERT INTO categories (category_name, parent_id, is_active)
            VALUES ('animals', 0, 1);

/*INSERT ALL THE CATEGORIES IN PAIRS TO TEMP TABLE*/
            CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempcat(parent nvarchar(256), child nvarchar(256));
            INSERT INTO tempcat
            VALUES ('animals', 'domestic'),('domestic', 'dog'),('domestic','cat');

/*INSERT INTO THE CATEGORIES TABLE*/
            INSERT INTO categories(category_name, parent_id, is_active)
            SELECT tempcat.child, categories.id, 1            
            FROM categories
            INNER JOIN tempcat
            ON categories.category_name = tempcat.parent;
            WHERE categories.is_active = 1;

/*DISPOSE THE TEMPORARY TABLE*/
            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tempcat;
```

Issue:
After the query is run I expect 4 entries in the categories table.

[image: Expected]

But I only get 2.

[image: Actual]

I can see that the temp table has correct entries before doing the last inner join.
I can't seem to figure out why the categories table wouldn't have the other two rows.

Any guidance in the right direction is highly appreciated.

**Update #1**
Suppose the specifications said 'There cannot be two active categories with the same category name *that had the same parent IDs*'.
For example, if there were two strings as (animals/domestic/cat), (animals/outdoor/cat) there should be two entries for cat with IDs of domestic and outdoor as parent_id's.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's '5.6.46-log'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE categories (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>                          category_name VARCHAR(64), 
>                          parent_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>                          is_active CHAR(1) NULL,
>                          UNIQUE INDEX idx_name_active (category_name));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE source_data (path TEXT);
> INSERT INTO source_data VALUES ('animals/domestic/dog'), ('animals/domestic/cat');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE update_categories_table()
> BEGIN
> DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
> INSERT IGNORE INTO categories (category_name, parent_id, is_active)
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', 1), 0, '1'
> FROM source_data;
> iteration: LOOP
>     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt
>     FROM source_data
>     WHERE LOCATE('/', path);
>     IF NOT cnt THEN 
>         LEAVE iteration;
>     END IF;
>     INSERT IGNORE INTO categories (category_name, parent_id, is_active)
>     SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_data.path, '/', 2), '/', -1),
>            categories.id,
>            '1'
>     FROM source_data, categories
>     WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(source_data.path, '/', 1) = categories.category_name;
>     UPDATE source_data
>     SET path = SUBSTRING(path FROM 1 + LOCATE('/', path));
> END LOOP iteration;
> TRUNCATE source_data;
> END
> ```

> ```
> call update_categories_table;
> SELECT * FROM categories;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | category_name | parent_id | is_active
> -: | :------------ | --------: | :--------
>  1 | animals       |         0 | 1        
>  4 | domestic      |         1 | 1        
>  7 | dog           |         4 | 1        
>  8 | cat           |         4 | 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09d08d0fb63251bde2a8ffaedc785353)*

Comment: Thanks. This does what the specifications asked for. Also it's quite easy to understand. `UNIQUE INDEX idx_name_active (category_name)` currently decides if a category name should be duplicated or not. 
I added an Update #1 to my post. How would I change the above line to achieve this?

Comment: Just for the record, I managed to achieve the above by adjusting the unique index `UNIQUE INDEX idx_name_active (category_name, parent_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8, you can do this with a single query:

```
with splits as (
      select 1 as n, substring_index(cats, '/', 1) as cat, cats
      from strings union all
      select 2 as n, substring_index(substring_index(cats, '/', 2), '/', -1) as cat, cats
      from strings 
      where cats like '%/%' union all
      select 3 as n, substring_index(substring_index(cats, '/', 3), '/', -1) as cat, cats 
      from strings
      where cats like '%/%/%'
     ),
     splits_n as (
      select s.*, dense_rank() over (order by n, cat) as new_id
      from splits s
     ),
     splits_np as (
      select s.*, sp.new_id as parent_id
      from splits_n s left join
           splits_n sp
           on sp.cats = s.cats and sp.n = s.n - 1
     ) 
select distinct new_id as id, cat, parent_id, 1 as is_active
from splits_np s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e9e792ce79b606b66d7fa49737eabae) is a db<>fiddle.

Unfortunately, this is much more painful in earlier versions.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this alternative solution you've shared. Working with [CTEs (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) is very convenient for a single query rather than creating a view. Thank you.